# Remove all text in parent div - keep string in children

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to remove all text inside a div - but unsure how to do this correctly with jQuery or vanilla JS. First I was thinking of using .empty but that remove my child's string as well.

Whats the correct way to do this? The string I want to remove is is the totaal: string. This is a dynamic text so I cant target the exact word.

```
<span id="span2">Totaal: <em id="headercartsum">€925</em></span>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case you want to remove the first child node of the `span` element, so you can do

```js
$('#span2').contents().eq(0).remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="span2">Totaal: <em id="headercartsum">€925</em></span>
```

---

or if you want to remove all text nodes children then

```js
$('#span2').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
}).remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="span2">Totaal: <em id="headercartsum">€925</em></span>
```

---

Based on a class of `em`.

```js
$('.headercartsum').map(function() {
  return this.previousSibling;
}).remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="span2">Totaal: <em id="headercartsum" class="headercartsum">€925</em></span>
```

Comment: That worked great, thanks! Also - would it be possible to remove the string before the em element based on the class if the em element?

Answer (score 2):

You can select text node by nodeType property along with `.remove()` to remove it:

```
$('#span2').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType === 3; //select text node
}).remove();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/veb5rn3a/)**

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$('#span2').html($('#span2>*'));
```

https://jsbin.com/boyebeyaxe/edit?html,js,output

Comment: better use #span2 > * or children(). it will probably go faster

Answer (score 0):

Select immediate children elements and make them the only content:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#span2").html( $("#span2").children() );
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kffj63zh/